# Dead Lettering Messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have dead lettering enabled for set of queues. But we have a requirement to either delete specific messages from dead letter queue or not dead letter them at all after TTL due to Legal Obligations. Since we have more than hundred thousand subscriptions in a namespace, we are ruling out the option of creating receivers on each dead letter queue and delete them.

Is there any way to not dead-letter specific messages even though topic has dead-lettering enabled? Is there any other way to address this requirement?

Comment: Are you using queue or topic ?

Comment: Have you considered consuming the queue using the [ReceiveAndDelete ReceiveMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.receivemode.aspx)? This way the message would be immediately removed from the queue without getting to the dead letter queue. However, in case you fail to handle the message due to a transient error this message would be lost and you won't have a second to handle it.

Comment: What happens with the messages that are not subject to the exclusion policy? Are they consumed by your system or something else is happening?

Comment: Messages are consumed by other systems. And we keep it in topic for certain period of time and then it would be dead-lettered. We cant disable deadletter because of other requirement.

Comment: You can try Auto forwarding dead letter queue messages to another queue and then process them